# Interruption, global variables and MainWindow in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, callback, portaudio

A friend and I are working on a simple synthesizer in C++. We have working oscillator, filter and envelope classes and are able to output some sounds using Portaudio libraries.

We are now working on the graphic interface with Qt Creator but are quite confused with how to organise everything. Indeed, portaudio uses a callback function to fill the buffer and to do so, it needs to access the getValue() method of the ocsillator or the process() method of the filter. But at the moment, we declared our oscillator object and our filter object as pointers inside the MainWindow class. We thus cannot access their methods in the callback function.

More informations on the callback function of portaudio can be found [here](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html).

Here are 2 solutions that I thought of :

- Putting all the synthesiser objects (osc, filter etc) as globals, so that I can access them in my callback function
- Putting the callback function and all the sound-related functions in main.cpp instead of mainwindow.cpp and having the MainWindow object as global, so that I can access its attributes (i.e. the oscillator etc. objects) in the callback function.

I don't really know which solution is the best, or if there is any that would work better...

Comment: Try to separate window and sound works as much as possible. E.g. define your ISoundEngine interface and call it from UI code. Callback function in this case should be in the code implementing ISoundEngine.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure it's all clear to me... Should I still put my synth objects in a SoundEngine class? But then do I put my SoundEngine object as global to access it from window and callback? (sorry I'm not very experienced in C++)

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to do it in this way. Also you could put SoundEngine object into your app class (if you have any) instead of making it global.